# Eclipse Juno - how to make the views minimize when they lose focus?

Tags: eclipse

When I work with eclipse, I like to have my Java editor maximized, and all other views minimized in the trim stack (the area around the edges of the window). This way, I can expand the view only when I need it, by clicking on the view icon.

In previous Eclipse versions, when I finished working with a view, I clicked on another view or the editor so that it lost focus, and that caused it to minimize again. In Juno, it doesn't work - when I click on the editor, the view stays open and is hiding my code. In order to close it, I have to either click the view icon, or click on another program and then return to Eclipse.

Do you have any idea if there is a setting I can change to get the old behavior back?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Seems like a bug in eclipse.

Comment: I know! This is extremely annoying, I hope there is a solution...

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371598 - are you using Juno SR1? This looks like it might be your bug and it's fixed there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce this problem using Juno SR1. [Bug 371598](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371598) was fixed and looks like the same problem.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384814 - is this the bug you are now seeing? If you are still seeing the issue even when the editor area is not empty I would recommend opening another bug against the Platform UI